# Compound Interest using scanner

Tags: java, time, rate, principal

```
import java.util.*;

class CompoundInterest

{
    
public static void main()

    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Enter Principal Amount");
        float p = s.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.println("Enter Time Period i.e. number of years");
        float t = s.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter Rate of Interest");
        float r = s.nextFloat();
        
        float a = p * (Math.pow(((1+ (r/100))), t));
        
        float ci = a-p;
        
        System.out.println("Compound Interest = " +ci);
        System.out.println("Amount = " +a);
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error like this:

> Loss of precision
>
> Required: float
>
> found : double
>
> 1 error

Answer (score 0):

Dude!!  java.lang.Math.pow(double,double) takes two double args and returns a double value..you have passed float params as actual params to that method..due to coercion they got converted to double.but while returning you are assigning returned value to a float value where automatic coercion is not possible!!
So either cast it to float explicitly or assign it to a double variable....at any cost it should return only double value